# JQuery to Javascript click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help with converting JQuery to Javascipt.

Im trying to is, by clicking the ‘Change Size’ button result in a call to the new sizeObject.changeSize function and a change to both the Size object’s isSize
variable and the size of the light div in the browser

I dont want to change the HTML. Need help with converting the .click function

```
var sizeObject;

function createSize(){

    //Size object initialisation

    sizeObject = new Size();


    // size-related event handlers

    $('#change').click(function(){
        Size.changeSize();
    });

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeObject.changeSize()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$('#change').click(function(){
  Size.changeSize();
});
```

Use :

```
var elem = document.getElementById("change"); 
elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Size.changeSize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular Javascript function for binding event handlers is `addEventListener`.

```
document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sizeObject.changeSize();
});
```